# How to Loop through JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have simple JS loop

```
jQuery('#checkbox-counter').live('click', function(){
    jQuery.get('index.php?option=get_site_list=true', 
        function(data){
            console.log(data[1]);
            for(var index in data[1].id){
                console.log(data[1].id[index]);
                console.log(data[1].name[index]);
            }
        },
        'JSON'
    )
});
```

The problem is shown in the screen

[image]

It also prints some jquery code(in source) or shows functions in console... Where is the problem?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen get values from object through loop

Comment: Well, that's what the code is doing - and some of those values are undefined, or are functions objects or are other Objects. Can you explain why this is a problem for you? It's not obvious from reading your question.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen problem is on the screen - some functions appears after values

Comment: `jQuery.get('index.php?option=get_site_list=true'` o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data[1].id` and `data[1].name` properties you are looping through are arrays, so you should use a conventional `for` loop rather than `for..in`:

```
        for(var index = 0; index < data[1].id.length; index++){
            console.log(data[1].id[index]);
            console.log(data[1].name[index]);
        }
```

When you use `for..in` it gives you other properties besides just the numerically indexed ones.

Comment: 1 problem - if array is for exampl 0,2,3,4 (there isn't 1) - loop doesn't work...

Comment: You can test `if (data[1].id[index] != undefined) ...`, but although a JavaScript array can have "missing" elements your data comes from JSON and JSON doesn't support sparse arrays so I don't see how you'd have a problem in this case. (Not with the square bracket array syntax as shown in your question with `["8","4"]` - you can simulate a sparse array by using an object, but it would be silly for whatever process produces that JSON string to use a proper array with square brackets some of the time and a pretend array with curly brackets at other times.)